# Anime involving two types of people, one can turn into weapons, while the other can wield those weapons. The main character is a girl

Tags: story-identification, anime

I need to find the name of an anime I watched about five years ago.

It takes place in a world where there are two types of people; one that can turn into weapons and one that can wield those weapons. There is a specific academy for them.

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. You could improve this question by taking a look at the guidance in [this post](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/11875/122024), and then editing the question to include any more details about the anime you can think of.

Comment: Laurel's answer is correct but Starrk and Lilynette from Bleach deserve an honourable mention.

Comment: And another honourable mention for Valkyrie Drive, which is another anime about pairs of girls, one type that turn into weapons and one that can wield them.

Answer (score 19):

Probably [Soul Eater](https://myanimelist.net/anime/3588/Soul_Eater):

> Soul Eater Evans, a Demon Scythe who only seems to care about what's cool, aims to become a Death Scythe with the help of his straight-laced wielder, or meister, Maka Albarn. The contrasting duo work and study alongside the hot headed Black☆Star and his caring weapon Tsubaki, as well as the Shinigami's own son, Death the Kid, an obsessive-compulsive dual wielder of twin pistols Patty and Liz.
>
> Soul Eater follows these students of Shibusen as they take on missions to collect souls and protect the city from the world's threats while working together under the snickering sun to become sounder in mind, body, and soul.
> — MAL

If not, [Soul Eater NOT!](https://myanimelist.net/anime/21507/Soul_Eater_NOT)

Comment: Yes! Tysm! It’s soul eater not!

Comment: @Tiana You can also accept the answer as correct :)